# Discord.py Reaction autorole Error : Instance of 'reactions' has no 'reaction_message' member

Tags: python, discord.py

So I'm trying to make a bot for my school, the objective is to create a bot schoolwide that could automatically assign the students to they’re roles so that they can access to their class specific channel. It’ll be so cool to have one way of communicating across the school.
So I picked a cool tutorial from YouTube
Here’s the link if you want to : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WQsQERxtD2w&list=PLYeOw6sTSy6ZGyygcbta7GcpI8a5-Cooc&index=29&t=1177s&ab_channel=CarberraTutorials
and it seems to be perfect so I did it :

```
1 from discord.ext.commands import Cog
2 from discord.ext import commands
3
4 client  = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
5
6class reactions(Cog):
7  def __init__(self, bot):
8     self.bot = bot 
9@Cog.listener()
10async def on_ready(self):
11        if not self.bot.ready:
12            self.filière = { # In French "filière" means a course of study that you take in high school
  13              "" : (809130298452869126), #Proffesioenl 
   14             "‍" : (809130233835683901), # thecnologique 
   15             "‍" : (809130260678311997), # generale
    16        }
    17        **self.reaction.message** = await self.bot.get_channel(809123408720822284).fetch_message(812283647490392104)
    18        self.bot.cogs_ready.ready_up("reactions")
19
20@Cog.listener()
21 async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
22    if self.bot.ready and payload.message_id == **self.reaction_message.id:**
23        print(payload.emoji.name)
24        role = self.bot.guild.get_role(self.filière[payload.emoji.name])
25        await payload.member.add.roles(role, reason="Choix de la filière")
26
27@Cog.listener()
28async def on_raw_reaction_remove(self, payload):
29    if self.bot.ready and payload.message_id == **self.reaction_message.id:**
30        member = self.bot.guild.get_member(payload.user_id)
31        await member.remove_roles(self.filière[payload.emoji.name], reason="Choix de la filière")
```

And now I'm facing a problem here are the 3 errors I get : ( I added the lines to show were the problem are, I also added a bold font were Visual Studio Code says the error is )

- Instance of 'reactions' has no 'reaction' member line 17
- Instance of 'reactions' has no 'reaction_message' member line 22
- Instance of 'reactions' has no 'reaction_message' member line 29

So if you got a solution it would be welcomed

Answer (score 0):

**self.reaction.message** on line 17 should be **self.reaction_message**, maybe?